# Only import ascending values from CSV to List - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to only import part of a CSV file to a list.

In short, the CSV I recveive contains two columns [depth and speed]. Depth always starts at zero, gets larger and then back to zero again.

I would like to add the first part of the CSV to the list (depth 0-13+). I then want to add the second part of the CSV (13-0) to another list.

I assume a for loop would be the way to go, but I don't know how to check each row for ascending/descending numbers.

```
pullData = open("svp3.csv","r").read()
dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
depthArrayY = []
speedArrayX = []
depthArrayLength = len(depthArrayY)

for eachLine in dataArray:
    if len(eachLine)>1:
        x,y = eachLine.split(',')
        speedArrayX.append(round(float(x), 2))
        depthArrayY.append(round(float(y), 2))
```

Comment: So you want to add rows with increasing depths in one list and rows with decreasing depths in another list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), I think it will allow you for much more when you need to deal with imported data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('svp3.csv')

tmp = df[df.depth <= df.depth.shift(-1)].values
depth_increase = tmp[:,0]
speed_while_depth_increase = tmp[:,1]

tmp = df[df.depth > df.depth.shift(-1)].values
depth_decrease = tmp[:,0]
speed_while_depth_decrease = tmp[:,1]
```

Comment: Excellent work, thanks. I noticed that you had named the DataFrame as 'df.depth' which I assume should just be 'df'. I've renamed it and now have working code.

Comment: Hi @DaveStark, df.depth makes reference to the column with name 'depth', you can also referred as df['depth']

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your CSV has the first the depth column then the speed column.
Depth column had values from 0 to a certain max value say 14, then from 13 to 0 depth column->[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
and I populated speed column with some random values.
The following code makes use of pandas library and splits the column of depth into 2 lists of ascending and descending values using a simple logic of storing the current max value to determine when the ascending part of the column ends.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('svp3.csv')

max_val = -10000
depthArrayAscendingY = []
speedArrayX = []
depthArrayDescendingY = []

for a in data.values:
    if a[0]>max_val:
        depthArrayAscendingY.append(a[0])
        speedArrayX.append(a[1])
        max_val = a[0]
    else:
        depthArrayDescendingY.append(a[0])
        speedArrayX.append(a[1])
```

The answer to this question by Baleato is more efficient and cleaner than this answer, you should definitely check their answer.